# How to assign assessment per subquestion to an array in limesurvey

Tags: limesurvey

I have an array that contains multiple subquestions, all I want is assign diferent assessments per subquestions cause LimeSurvey allows to put just one assessment per question.

Answer (score 0):

Then : don't use assessments but Equation question type : https://manual.limesurvey.org/Expression_Manager#Assessments_.3D.3E_Equations_and_.C2.A0Micro-Tailoring